# ASP.NET Web API config to receive authentication Azure B2C token from Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0, restful-authentication

I am working on Angular SPA to ASP.NET Web API-2 authentication via Azure B2C. I have managed to authenticate and receive token from Azure B2C inside Angular Presentation.

My question is how I configure server side implementation to receive token and authenticate user to consume web API. At the movement I cannot see token received from angular unless I am looking at wrong place.

At Angular side I am using RXJS to consume services and token is wrapped in header

### Angular service

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, RequestMethod, Request, Connection, ConnectionBackend} from '@angular/http';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

 public getMessageFromWebAPI_T1():Observable<IMessageA[]>
 {
    const requestOptions = new RequestOptions({
        method: RequestMethod.Get,
        url: 'https://localhost:44370/app/MyFunction/GetMessage',
    });

      requestOptions.headers = new Headers();           

      requestOptions.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      requestOptions.headers.set("Authorization", this.token)

    return this.http.request(new Request(requestOptions))
                    .map((response:Response)=> response.json())                       
}
```

### Startup.cs

```
  public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAutoMapper();
        services.AddSingleton(c => Configuration);
        services.AddCors(o=> {
            o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => {
                builder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin();
            });
        });
        services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();

        services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddAzureAdB2CBearer(options =>
        {
            Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);
        });

        //Policies and requirement handlers registration

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AdministratorOnly", policy =>
                policy.Requirements.Add(new UserClaimRequirement("Administrator")));

            options.AddPolicy("AnalistOnly", policy =>
                policy.Requirements.Add(new UserClaimRequirement("Analist")));

        });

        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, UserClaimAuthorizationHandler>();


        //Handling all above to Structure Map
        return ConfigureIoC(services);
    }
```

### Controller

```
[Authorize]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("app/[controller]")]
public class MyFunctionController : BaseAntController
{

  [Route("[action]")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetMessage()
    {
        IList<MessageA> messageA = new List<MessageA> {            
            new MessageA {id=1, title="message A", detail="detail A"},
            new MessageA {id=2, title="message B", detail="detail B"},
            new MessageA {id=3, title="message C", detail="detail C"},
            new MessageA {id=4, title="message D", detail="detail D"},
        };

        return new ObjectResult(messageA); 
    }
    .....
```

Comment: are you using `http` or `httpClient`

Comment: http in angular from rxjs

Comment: update question with import list

Comment: i have managed to wrap token in header but .net core config,,, i believe i am missing something... as its not showing any repose with [Authorization] attribute in web api controller but without attribute it does call back end web api